# js sliding menu help -- animation delay in the middle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking to make a menu that has some kind of specific functions. I'm relatively new to javascript and jquery so I have no idea where to start. Here is what I want it to do:

[image: js problem]

Hovering over link 4 and 5 also continue to make them stay in their end-animation state.

Any suggestions? I tried doing this with CSS3 animations but I can't get it to pause after the user stops hovering over link 3 before sliding back. I also ran into the issue of the gap between link 3 and link 4 causing the hover to stop. Javascript just seems like the better choice.

[jsfiddle of my css3 animations](http://jsfiddle.net/fMGva/)

This is the relevant code that has my css3 animations in it:

```
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all .2s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all .2s ease 0s;
 -ms-transition: all .2s ease 0s;
 transition: all .2s ease 0s;
```

edit: I've updated it with the jsfiddle of my current CSS3 animation (it looks a bit different in the live preview on jsfiddle than on my website).

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some code you can show us? It would help providing you an answer.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin! I've tried finding open source jquery that I can edit to fit my webpage but no luck. :( I can post my css3 animations that I have so far if you want.

Comment: You could start by doing that. Somebody may have a solution without the need of jQuery, just with css3. You should then also tag your question `css3` next to the current tags, so more people will see your question ;)

Comment: Also putting your current code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will help others to help you fix your problem :)

Comment: Ok I edited my post with my CSS3 menu and the jsfiddle! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The third 'li' of the top menu has been extended in width so that when you are moving your cursor over to the 'extralinks' menu, the latter doesn't slide out of view.

Pure CSS Solution: [Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ7Zm/4/)

**CSS**:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.links {
    width:100%;
}

.links > menu {
    left: 0%;
    text-align:center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
}

.links menu li  {
    whitespace: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    top: 24px;
    z-index: 4;
    float:left;
}

.links a, a:visited {
    font-family: RobotoLight;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transformation: none;
    weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    z-index: 4;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
}

.links a:hover {
    font-family: RobotoLight;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transformation: none;
    weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #33b5e5;
    z-index: 4;
}

.l3 .extralinks {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left:100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    text-align:center;
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 4;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease 0s;
    transition: all .2s ease 0s;
    z-index: 4;
}
.l3:hover .extralinks {
    left: 50%;    
}
.l3:hover .extralinks li {
}


.links li:nth-child(3) {
    width:200px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

.links li:nth-child(3):hover > a {
    font-family: RobotoLight;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transformation: none;
    weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #33b5e5;
    z-index: 4;                
    border-bottom: 3px solid #33b5e5;
}


.links li:hover > a, li:active > a {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #33b5e5;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="links">
    <menu>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="l3">
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <menu class="extralinks">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                </li>
            </menu>
        </li>
    </menu>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was considering, but I ran into the issue that I had a border on the bottom of the 3rd li that shows up on hover, and that would be wayyyyy too big on the actual navigation bar. If there was some way to cut off the border on one side I would use this method, but I haven't been able to find one yet.